# Question regarding notation in integrals (measure theory)

Tags: measure-theory, notation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, product-measure

The definition of a product measure is given as

$$
(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)(A) =\int_{\Omega_1} \mu_2(A_{\omega_1})\mu_1(d\omega_1) 
$$

This is the same as

$$
(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)(A) =\int_{\Omega_1} \mu_2(A_{\omega_1})d\mu_1  
$$

where $\omega_1 \in \Omega_1 \in \mathcal{A_1}$ with measure $\mu_1$.

Is this correct or does $\mu_1(d\omega_1) $ mean something else?

Comment: Both notations are used.